# Install a program with apt-offline

Tags: apt, package-management

I have been researching about offline package management and followed the apt-offline tutorials as [this](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT). For all documentations say that let create a signature on offline machine like this: `apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig` and this will generate all information required from apt about updating its database. I have done this. But I want to do `apt-get install vim`, for example. How can we generate the signature to install vim? I could not find the main reason I am using apt-offline.
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To install the package vim you have first to create a signature for the installation on the **off line machine**:

```
sudo apt-offline set vim-offline.sig --install-packages vim
```

Then on the **on line machine** you download the packages:

```
apt-offline get vim-offline.sig --bundle vim-install.zip
```

Finally on the **off line machine** you install it:

```
sudo apt-offline install vim-install.zip
```

Vim and all its dependencies should have been installed properly on the off line machine.

Comment: after doing above steps I used apt-get install <packageName> and it installed package from apt cache

Answer (score 3):

The sig file has information on updating the certain package with a database, but it does not hold the actual package if you did not have it previously installed. The overall steps are:

### Step 1 (Already Completed by OP)

Generate a signature file on the disconnected machine at home:

```
apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig
```

The above command will generate all information required from apt about updating its database.

By default, with no additional arguments passed, `apt-offline` will extract information about **APT Package Database Update i.e. the `--update` option** as well as the list of **Packages to be upgraded i.e. the `--upgrade` option.**

These options can also be individually passed if you want only one of those.

### Step 2

Download data based on the signature file generated earlier:

```
apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.sig --threads 5
```

The above command will download data as mentioned in the signature file. To speed up downloads (that can be from multiple apt repositories), in this example, we spawn 5 download threads.

**Note:** It would be good to also download the bug reports for the packages that you are downloading. So that example now becomes:

```
apt-offline get C:\apt-offline.sig --bug-reports --threads 5
```

There are many more options that you can pass to `apt-offline`, like the `--bundle` option which would generate an archive file with all of the data.

Once completed, you could just copy the data (an archive file, if you used the `--bundle` option) back to the removable medium and copy it back onto your offline host.

### Step 3

Once you're back upon the home machine, you feed the data from the removable medium to `apt-offline`:

```
apt-offline install /media/USB/apt-offline.zip
```

This will update the APT database on your disconnected machine seamlessly.

If there were packages that needed to be upgraded, now they would all be available (with dependencies) in the APT database. So, if you do an `apt-get upgrade` now, APT won't prompt you mentioning even a single byte download. APT would find that all required packages are already present in the APT cache.

If you had used the `--bug-reports` switch that I mentioned earlier, during install, `apt-offline` would prompt you with the list of bug reports related to the packages on your machine that need be upgraded/installed - not just the list, but the full bug report will be available for you to look at and evaluate the severity involved.

**All credit goes to [Offline Package Management for APT](https://debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT).**

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled enough with apt-offline.
Instead I propose to just copy everything or only the relevant from `/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` from another partition or machine with same parameters where these are available to the same location on your system.
Then just run

```
apt get install name_of_your_packages`
```

and enjoy.
This will work because `apt install` will first look in these directories.
I hope this helped, if so, +1, like, spread the world!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @TheOdd's great answer, I also needed to install apt-offline itself offline.  To do this for example on Ubuntu 20.04, I found the packages I needed:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/apt-offline

https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/python3-magic

Then found and downloaded the deb files from here:

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/apt-offline_1.8.2-1_all.deb.html

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/python3-magic_0.4.15-3_all.deb.html

And manually copied to my offline machine and installed the deb packages with dpkg -i command.  Don't just use the GUI to install deb files as it might fail to report errors.