# Offline update Ubuntu 20.04 CD repository

Tags: updates, offline

is it any possibility to seal the first update of packages for Ubuntu 20.04? Let me explain the problem faced and not found on internet as a solution. Immediately after installing of Ubuntu 20.04 it is recommended to use "apt-get upgrade" to  have the latest main packages updated, then installing customs needed packages.

Everything is ok and work, but I want to perform whole these update of packages with download somewhere and to make a CD or DVD for later use packages for updated and installed offline (no internet), to be possible later to install another PC with same release packages even if I will install 2 months later when internet has new releases. So I want to have same installation of release packages anytime later offline.

Is it possible such of thing?

Comment: For an offline system, periodic LTS upgrades may not be worth the effort. You will get a newer kernel (for hardware compatibility), security patches, and bugfixes...NOT "latest main packages," but merely incremental fixes to software versions that you already have. If your hardware works well and you are not bothered by any major bugs, then you might not notice a difference.

Comment: for development platform I need to have a stable and same platform onto more than one PC, so I'm really interested in this how to do it.

Comment: the tool you are looking for is `apt-offline` see e.g.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/835655/install-a-program-with-apt-offline especially the answer by TheOdd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install a program with apt-offline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835655/install-a-program-with-apt-offline)

Comment: I used this command "apt-offline set /tmp/apt-offline.sig" to generate signature on offline PC. Then I moved the signature to the online PC and I run the following command "apt-offline get -d /tmp/myapt /tmp/apt-offline.sig". So the online PC started to download packages for upgrading the offline PC but for some of packages I've got errors:

Comment: ERROR: Giving up on URL http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-all/Packages.lzma